# Why is my AWS RDS (postgres) at a high percentage of cpu with no active sessions?

Tags: amazon-rds, cpu

I have two postgres db, prod and dev.  Lately, dev has been *really* slow, so I checked into it, and it appears to be using CPU credits faster than I'm getting them.  I could not figure out why, so I checked the cpu usage history, and it appears that after a strange spike, the baseline has settled to twice the usage it was before:

[image]

I could not find any active sessions which would warrant such cpu usage, but just to be sure, I stopped the db, let it sit for a bit, then started it again.  Even after a fresh start, though, the cpu usage is still strangely high, even as compared to a very similar db:

[image]

**How can I figure out what all of this usage is coming from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will always work, but what managed to be effective for me was switching to a different instance, then switching back.

To do so, go up to `Modify` button in the `RDS > Databases > [MY_DB}` view, and then change your instance to any other instance type, wait for the update, then switch back.

I suppose I just had a bad ec2.mirco, and the method above got me a different (better) one which does not exhaust more cpu credits at idle than it gains.

[image]

Comment: I had an issue with my t2.micro RDS PG instance that I wasn't able to find the root cause for. Normally, it hovers around 7.5-8% CPU, which is below the 10% baseline,  accruing credits over time. For the last 2 months it was averaging just above 10%, losing about 20 CPU Credits a week. As a gamble, I decided to do a Stop Temporarily and Restart action, which effectively moves the instance to new underlying infrastructure. It seems to have worked; the Average CPU is now normal and I'm accruing credits again

![CPU Usage](https://imgur.com/a/e82Id8B)

Comment: Also wanted to add that the Stop/Start took about 10 mins downtime for a 20GB capacity instance.